# Switch data structure from dictionary of tuples to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python

```
#Queries
espanol_3d_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=1, xd=None, vip=None)
espanol_3d = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=None, xd=None, vip=None)
espanol_3d_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, vip=1, gtmax=None, xd=None)
espanol_3d_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, xd=1, gtmax=None, vip=None)
espanol_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", gtmax=1, tipo_3d=None, vip=None, xd=None)
espanol = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", gtmax=None, tipo_3d=None, vip=None, xd=None)
espanol_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", vip=1, gtmax=None, tipo_3d=None, xd=None)
espanol_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", xd=1, vip=None, gtmax=None, tipo_3d=None)
subtitulada_3d_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=1, xd=None, vip=None)
subtitulada_3d = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1,  gtmax=None, xd=None, vip=None)
subtitulada_3d_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, vip=1, gtmax=None, xd=None)
subtitulada_3d_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, xd=1, vip=None, gtmax=None)
subtitulada_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", gtmax=1, tipo_3d=None, xd=None, vip=None)
subtitulada = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", gtmax=None, tipo_3d=None, vip=None, xd=None)
subtitulada_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", vip=1, gtmax=None, tipo_3d=None, xd=None)
subtitulada_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", xd=1, vip=None, gtmax=None, tipo_3d=None)

#Creating a dictionary of all types of funciones querysets
func_tags = ['espanol', 'subtitulada', 'espanol_3d', 'subtitulada_3d', 'espanol_3d_gtmax', 'espanol_vip', 'espanol_xd', 'subtitulada_3d_gtmax', 'subtitulada_3d_vip',
 'espanol_3d_vip', 'espanol_3d_xd', 'espanol_gtmax', 'subtitulada_3d_xd', 'subtitulada_gtmax', 'subtitulada_vip', 'subtitulada_xd']
func_all = [espanol, subtitulada, espanol_3d, subtitulada_3d, espanol_3d_gtmax, espanol_vip, espanol_xd, subtitulada_3d_gtmax, subtitulada_3d_vip, espanol_3d_vip, espanol_3d_xd,
espanol_gtmax, subtitulada_3d_xd, subtitulada_gtmax, subtitulada_vip, subtitulada_xd]

funciones = dict(zip(func_tags, func_all))

#Removing empty element from funciones dictionary
for x in list(funciones.keys()):
    if not (funciones[x]).exists():
        del funciones[x]

cine_tags = []

for key, value in funciones.iteritems():
    for item in value:
        cine_tags.append(item.idcine.nombre)

cine_tags_unique = list(set(cine_tags))
horarios = {}

for cine in cine_tags_unique:
    horarios[cine] = []

#Appending func_tags and funciones to the horarios dictionary organized by cine
for key, value in funciones.iteritems():
    for item in value:
        for in_key, value in horarios.iteritems():
            if in_key == item.idcine.nombre:
                horarios[in_key].append((key, item))
```

---

Aditional info:

Funcion : a django queryset that represents showtimes from a movie in a movie theather.

The type of funciones options:

```
['espanol', 'subtitulada', 'espanol_3d', 'subtitulada_3d', 'espanol_3d_gtmax', 'espanol_vip', 'espanol_xd', 'subtitulada_3d_gtmax', 'subtitulada_3d_vip','espanol_3d_vip', 'espanol_3d_xd', 'espanol_gtmax', 'subtitulada_3d_xd', 'subtitulada_gtmax', 'subtitulada_vip', 'subtitulada_xd']
```

Movie Theaters options:

```
[u'Cinemark Plaza de las Americas', u'Cineplex', u'Multicines CCI', u'Supercines Quicentro Sur', u'Supercines San Luis', u'Multicines Recreo', u'Multicines Scala', u'Mis Cines', u'Multicines Condado']
```

Now I have a dictionary of tuples structured like this:

```
'Movie theather': [(type_of_funcion, funcion_object), (type_of_funcion, funcion_object)], 'Another Movie Theater': [(type_of_funcion, funcion_object)],...
```

Sample data with the dict that I have now looks like this:

```
{u'Cinemark Plaza de las Americas': [('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #540: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #541: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #542: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #548: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #549: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #550: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #530: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #531: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #532: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #533: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #508: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #509: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #510: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #511: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>)], u'Cineplex': [('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cineplex, Funcion #454: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cineplex, Funcion #455: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cineplex, Funcion #456: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cineplex, Funcion #451: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cineplex, Funcion #452: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cineplex, Funcion #453: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>)], u'Multicines CCI': [('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #158: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #160: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #165: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #166: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #168: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #431: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #434: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #436: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #438: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol', <Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #439: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>)]}
```

The problem with this is that I have 'repeated' types of funciones like this:

```
{u'Cinemark Plaza de las Americas': [('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #540: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #541: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('subtitulada_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #542: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>), ('espanol_3d', <Funcion: Cinemark Plaza de las Americas, Funcion #548: The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey>),
```

Instead of that I would like to group by types of funciones that belong to a movie theater, something like this:

```
{u'Cinemark Plaza de las Americas': { {'subtitulada': Funcion1, Funcion2, Funcion3}, {'subtitulada_3d': Funcion4, Fucion5} }, next_movie_theather: {},...}
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: you're much more to get a good answer if you make your example reproducible. You might use a toy data set, for example.

Comment: Also note that this question doesn't actually need to mention Django or show the view (if you give a toy dataset like the one in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make such a transformation in one line using a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {"a": [(1, "x"), (2, "y")], "b": [(10, "w"), (1, "z")]}

new_d = {k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print new_d
# {'a': {1: 'x', 2: 'y'}, 'b': {1: 'z', 10: 'w'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, its somehow truncating results, I will edit my question and provide toy data to illustrate my problem better.

Comment: Just a guess- are there duplicate keys (that is, items in the first part of more than one tuple?)

Comment: Yes David, there are. I have edited the question, does it provide a better idea of what i have? THanks

Comment: @Edu: If there are duplicate keys, then it is impossible for them to be a dictionary (since each key in a dictionary can map to only one value).

Comment: Yup, you're right David, instead of trying to convert the tuple, Can I just store it as a dictionary before instead of a tuple? The loop where I do it is the following:                                    `for key, value in funciones.iteritems():
    for item in value:
        for in_key, value in horarios.iteritems():
            if in_key == item.idcine.nombre:
                horarios[in_key].append((key, item))`

Comment: I have also updated the question to include how i create the data structure

Comment: I ended up having to edit my data structure to get the output I was looking for. Your answer was good for this question though.